# Approach behind having everything as an object in Python

Tags: python

Why is everything in Python, an object? According to what I read, everything including functions is an object. It's not the same in other languages. So what prompted this shift of approach, to treat everything including, even functions, as objects.

Comment: Very relevant: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2015-June/691689.html

Comment: While the question is interesting, this is not really the place to talk about language design choices. Besides, unless GVR himself come here, the answers will probably be opinion-based.

Comment: Instead of closing this question, shouldn't it be moved to programmers.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: And could the serial downvoter to all answers of this thread explain his behavior?

Comment: @Jivan I wouldn't see it as _serial downvoting_, IMHO they are all pretty weak answers.

Answer (score -1):

The power of everything being an object is that you can define behavior for each object. For example a function being an object gives you an easy way to access the docs of the function for introspection.

```
print( function.__doc__ )
```

The alternative would be to provide a library of function that took
a function and returned its interesting properties.

```
import function_lib
print( function_lib.get_doc( function )
```

Making int, str etc classes means that you can extend those provide types
in interesting ways for your problem domain.

Answer (score -1):

***why is everything in Python, an object?***

Python (unlike other languages) is a truly Object Orient language (aka OOP)
when everything is an object, it becomes easier to search, manipulate or access things. (But everything comes at the cost of speed)

*what **prompted** this shift of approach, to treat everything including, even functions, as objects?*

"Necessity is the mother of invention"

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, the 'Everything is object' is great in Python. In this language, you don't react to what are the objects you have to handle, but how they can interact. A function is just an object that you can `__call__`, a list is just an object that you can `__iter__`. But why should we divide data in non overlapping groups. An object can behave like a function when we call it, but also like an array when we access it.

This means that you don't think your "function" like, "i want an array of integers and i return the sum of it" but more "i will try to iterate over the thing that someone gave me and try to add them together, if something goes wrong, i will tell it to the caller by `raise`ing  error and he will hate to modify his behavior".

The most interesting exemple is `__add__`. When you try something like `Object1 + Object2`, Python will ask (nicely ^^) to `Object1` to try to add himself with `object2` (`Object1.__add__(Object2))`. There is 2 scenarios here: either `Oject1` knows how to add himself to `Object2` and everything is fine, either he raises a `NotImplemented` error and Python will ask to `Object2` to radd himself to `Object1`. Just with this mechanism, you can teach to your object to add themselves with any other object, you can manage commutativity,...